# Spring Rest Controller method not invoked with path variable and http request as arguments

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest

This is my controller method

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    @GetMapping("/quiz/{quizId}/identifyfromsixjson")
      @ResponseBody
      UserProfileQuestion playIdentifyFromSix(@PathVariable String quizId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ... Calling service method  ... here
      }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/myproject
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

So when I make a GET request to http://localhost:8080/myproject/identifyfromsixjson/test, this is the response I see in Postman.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-08T02:42:14.387+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/myproject/quiz/test/identifyfromsixjson"
}
```

Startup logs

```
018-10-08 01:59:32.603  WARN 46035 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-10-08 01:59:32.641  INFO 46035 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/quiz/{quizId}/identifyfromsixjson]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.myproject.model.UserProfileQuestion> com.myproject.controller.ProfileController.fetchUserProfileAndHeadShot(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-08 01:59:32.644  INFO 46035 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-08 01:59:32.644  INFO 46035 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-10-08 01:59:32.672  INFO 46035 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/myproject] onto handler '/myproject'
2018-10-08 01:59:32.678  INFO 46035 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-08 01:59:32.678  INFO 46035 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add more information such as annotation you use for controller or what do you want to return?

Comment: add @RequestMapping("/myproject") in class

Comment: @trjade I have updated my post. I have annotated my controller as a rest controller.

Comment: do you have any other method with same url but with POST mapping?? pls add full controller code.

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan I have specified the context path in application.properties

Comment: @Alien I don't. This is the only function in the controller.

Comment: Try changing it to `@PathVariable(value = "quizId")`

Comment: why `https`? try use `http`.

Comment: @Katrik root context path is set like this: `server.servlet.context-path=/myproject` (you missed `servlet`) have a look at [common-application-properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Unrelated. Btw, `@ResponseBody` is pre-assumed (as you use `@RestController` that has the annotation included)

Answer (score 1):

This is the path you've defined:

`/quiz/{quizId}/identifyfromsixjson`

and this is the path you're testing with

`/identifyfromsixjson/test`

It should be apparent that they don't match, which is why you're getting that error.

You can do the following:

**1. Test with the path that you've defined:**

`http://localhost:8080/myproject/quiz/test/identifyfromsixjson`

**2. Update your path definition**

```
@GetMapping("/identifyfromsixjson/{quizId}")
@ResponseBody
UserProfileQuestion playIdentifyFromSix(@PathVariable String quizId,HttpServletRequest request) {
    ... Calling service method  ... here
}
```

and then test with

`http://localhost:8080/myproject/identifyfromsixjson/test`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to write a RestController. Annotate your controller with `@RestController`

```
    @RestController
    public class QuizController {
        @GetMapping("/identifyfromsixjson/{quizId}")
        @ResponseBody
        UserProfileQuestion playIdentifyFromSix(@PathVariable String quizId, HttpServletRequest request) {
          ... Calling service method  ... here
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is annotated as Restcontroller. I have updated my post.

Comment: @Kartik Please check if you have correct details in the question. You endpoint is different and you are testing with a different URL.